# javax.el.ELException: java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I´ve a query with multiple inner joins so it works perfectly when I run it on mysql workbench but when I run my application I get:

```
Advertencia: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.proximate.dto.OriginadorDetalleDTO
```

javax.el.ELException: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.proximate.dto.OriginadorDetalleDTO

Here is my method that executes the query:

```
@Override
public List<OriginadorDetalleDTO> getOriginadorDetalles(OriginadorDTO originador) throws DAOException {
    Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as NUM_GESTORES_ACTIVOS, M.ME_CVE_MSJ, " +
    " M.ME_DESCRIP, J.GESTORES_PERMITIDOS   \n" +
    " FROM gestores G \n" +
    " INNER JOIN usuarios U ON G.ID_SUPERVISOR = U.id\n" +
    " INNER JOIN mensajerias M ON U.ID_ORGANIZACION = M.ME_CVE_MSJ\n" +
    " INNER JOIN originadores O ON O.ID_SIAM = M.ME_CVE_CLIENTE\n" +
    " INNER JOIN mensajerias_gestores J ON J.ME_CVE_MSJ = M.ME_CVE_MSJ\n" +
    " WHERE U.ID_NIVEL = 4\n" +
    " AND ID_SIAM = :idSiam\n" +
    " GROUP BY M.ME_CVE_MSJ, M.ME_DESCRIP, J.GESTORES_PERMITIDOS");
    query.setParameter("idSiam", originador.getIdSIAM());
    List<OriginadorDetalleDTO> list = query.list();
    return list;
}
```

and here is my bean:

```
public class OriginadorDetalleDTO {
    private String idMensajeria;
    private String descMensajeria;
    private int numGestores;
    private int numGestoresActivos;

    public String getIdMensajeria() {
        return idMensajeria;
    }

    public void setIdMensajeria(String idMensajeria) {
        this.idMensajeria = idMensajeria;
    }

    public String getDescMensajeria() {
        return descMensajeria;
    }

    public void setDescMensajeria(String descMensajeria) {
        this.descMensajeria = descMensajeria;
    }

    public int getNumGestores() {
        return numGestores;
    }

    public void setNumGestores(int numGestores) {
        this.numGestores = numGestores;
    }

    public int getNumGestoresActivos() {
        return numGestoresActivos;
    }

    public void setNumGestoresActivos(int numGestoresActivos) {
        this.numGestoresActivos = numGestoresActivos;
    }

}
```

Does anyone knows why am I getting that error??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `query.list()` it returns a list of `Object[]` according your query but because you are casting (implicitly) to `List<OriginadorDetalleDTO>` it is throwing the exception. Perhaps you are after a `ResultTransformer` to get a `List<OriginadorDetalleDTO>` from your query.